# loadAfter method of Android Paging library calls itself continuously

Tags: android, kotlin, pagination, paging

Just after calling loadInitial method it automatically starts calling loadAfter method until and unless all pages are loaded and it gets an empty array from response. I am attaching my DataSource and DataSourceFactory code along with ViewModel function and PagedListAdapter.

PassbookDataSource.kt

```
    package co.indiagold.gold.buy.loan.home

import androidx.paging.PageKeyedDataSource
import co.indiagold.gold.buy.loan.helper.GenericMethods.handleServerError
import co.indiagold.gold.buy.loan.helper.GenericResponse
import co.indiagold.gold.buy.loan.network.Repository
import co.indiagold.gold.buy.loan.network.ResultWrapper
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class PassbookDataSource(private val accessToken: String, private val assetName:String,private val viewModelScope: CoroutineScope) : PageKeyedDataSource<Int, PassbookResponseModel>() {
    private val PAGE_SIZE = 20

    override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams<Int>, callback: LoadInitialCallback<Int, PassbookResponseModel>) {
        var result: ResultWrapper<GenericResponse<ArrayList<PassbookResponseModel>?>?>? = null
        viewModelScope.launch {
            result = Repository.getPassbookDetail(accessToken, assetName,1, PAGE_SIZE)
        }.invokeOnCompletion {
            if (result is ResultWrapper.Success) {
                val successResult = result as ResultWrapper.Success
                callback.onResult(successResult.value!!.result as MutableList<PassbookResponseModel>, null, 2)
            } else {
                it.handleServerError("vault/passbook")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun loadBefore(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, PassbookResponseModel>) {
    }

    override fun loadAfter(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, PassbookResponseModel>) {
        var result: ResultWrapper<GenericResponse<ArrayList<PassbookResponseModel>?>?>? = null
        viewModelScope.launch {
            result = Repository.getPassbookDetail(accessToken,assetName, params.key, PAGE_SIZE)
        }.invokeOnCompletion {
            if (result is ResultWrapper.Success) {
                val successResult = result as ResultWrapper.Success
                callback.onResult(successResult.value!!.result as MutableList<PassbookResponseModel>, params.key+1)
            } else {
                it.handleServerError("vault/passbook")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PassbookDataSourceFactory.kt

```
class PassbookDataSourceFactory(private val accessToken:String,private val assetName:String,private val viewModelScope:CoroutineScope) : DataSource.Factory<Int,PassbookResponseModel>(){

    val orderListMLD = MutableLiveData<PassbookDataSource>(null)
    var orderDataSource : PassbookDataSource? = null

    override fun create(): DataSource<Int, PassbookResponseModel> {
        orderDataSource = PassbookDataSource(accessToken,assetName,viewModelScope)
        orderListMLD.postValue(orderDataSource)
        return orderDataSource!!
    }
}
```

Viewmodel Function

```
fun getPassbookDetail(assetName: String) {
        val accessToken = GenericMethods.getDataFromPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFS.LOGIN_PREFERENCES, Constants.SHARED_PREFS.ACCESS_TOKEN)
        if (accessToken.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            handleNullAccessTokenCase()
        } else {
            val factory = PassbookDataSourceFactory(accessToken, assetName, viewModelScope)

            val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
                .setInitialLoadSizeHint(10)
                .setPrefetchDistance(4)
                .build()

            val executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)

            passbookResponseMLD = LivePagedListBuilder(factory, config)
                .setFetchExecutor(executor)
                .build()
        }
    }
```

PassbookAdapter.kt

```
package co.indiagold.gold.buy.loan.home

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.paging.PagedList
import androidx.paging.PagedListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import co.indiagold.gold.buy.loan.databinding.CardPassbookBinding
import co.indiagold.gold.buy.loan.helper.Constants
import co.indiagold.gold.buy.loan.orders.OrdersActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.card_passbook.view.*

class PassbookAdapter(private val activity: Activity,private val emptyListListener: EmptyListListener) : PagedListAdapter<PassbookResponseModel,PassbookAdapter.MyHolder>(PASSBOOK_DIFF_CALLBACK) {

    private lateinit var binding: CardPassbookBinding
    class MyHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyHolder {
        binding = CardPassbookBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))
        emptyListListener.onListLoad(currentList?.size)
        return MyHolder(binding.root)
    }

    override fun onCurrentListChanged(previousList: PagedList<PassbookResponseModel>?, currentList: PagedList<PassbookResponseModel>?) {
        super.onCurrentListChanged(previousList, currentList)
        emptyListListener.onListLoad(currentList?.size)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyHolder, position: Int) {
        binding.passbookEntry = getItem(position)

        holder.itemView.passbookRootLayout.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(activity,OrdersActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(Constants.BUNDLE_STRINGS.ORDER_ID,getItem(position)?.referenceId)
            activity.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return getItem(position)!!.createdAt
    }

    /*override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return position
    }*/
}



private val PASSBOOK_DIFF_CALLBACK = object  : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<PassbookResponseModel>(){
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: PassbookResponseModel, newItem: PassbookResponseModel): Boolean {
        return oldItem.createdAt == newItem.createdAt
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: PassbookResponseModel, newItem: PassbookResponseModel): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

[image: Proof of multiple calls]

Comment: Did you figure out what the issue was?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that you may put recycler view inside NextedScrollview or ScrollView, by removing scrollview it will work fine